# How to use Application objects in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the Global.asax I added a few values to the application object:

```
Application.Add("First", "One");
Application.Add("Second", "Two");
Application.Add("Third", "Three");
Application.Add("Forth", "Four");
```

How do I use them in my controller?

I tried:

```
var x = Application("First");
```

But `Application` is giving me an error, it says `cannot resolve symbol Application`

Comment: which `Application` class is this? what not found error?

Comment: Have you tried spelling "First" the same everywhere?

Comment: If this is really C#, then you want `Application["First"]`

Comment: @AntP Spelling is not the mistake, that was just a typo when i was typing here.

Comment: @john how would I use it? it still says `cannot resolve symbol Application`

Comment: Try using `HttpContext.Application`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a controller action, it would be `HttpContext.Application["First"]`.

If you're in a static method or outside a controller, you could do `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["First"]`.